# Wagtail - Add data to streamfield CharBlock on save()

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm trying to automatically fill in a specific charblock on a streamfield I have created on save and I can get it to change but not save because when the page refreshes the new data is not there.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('update_fields'):
            if self.auto_update:
                for product in self.product_details.raw_data:
                    product_name = product['value']['product_name']
                    product_url = product['value']['product_url']

                    # I'm trying to set the field data here
                    product['value']['product_snippet_url'] = 'Test'
                    # when I print, I see the 'Test' value in the dict
                    print(product)          
        else:
            # Do stuff on publish()
            pass

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
    # Streamfield Block
    class ProductNameAndUrlBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
        product_name = blocks.CharBlock(required=True, help_text='Add product name')
        product_url =  blocks.URLBlock(required=True, help_text='Add Product URL')
        product_snippet_url = blocks.CharBlock(required=False, help_text='Link to snippet')
```

The above code is for testing purposes, my end goal is to insert the url of the related snippet there and then use JS to turn it into a button so when someone clicks on it, it links to the snippet page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing back to the stream's `raw_data` property will not reliably save the data. `raw_data` is a "backup" copy of the data as retrieved from the database, in a simplified format - for example, a PageChooserBlock value is stored there as a plain ID rather than a Page object. Once data is read or written through the stream's standard methods (e.g. looping over `for block in self.product_details` or writing `self.product_details[0] = ...`), the `raw_data` entry is treated as stale and not looked at again.

The correct approach is to read and write the stream itself as a list, rather than going through `raw_data`:

```
            for product in self.product_details:
                product_name = product.value['product_name']
                product_url = product.value['product_url']

                # I'm trying to set the field data here
                product.value['product_snippet_url'] = 'Test'
```

Comment: Thank you for that infoit was very heplful, however, it's not saving. It should be saved with "return super().save(*args, **kwargs)" right?

Comment: Thank you this works. The issue was that I was testing this with draft but the draft updated details do not show after saving the draft, I had to move it under the Else block